# Opening ArcCatalog within ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

After reinstallation of arcmap (10.2.1), when I click on ArcMap, only the display window opens and does not show any other options including ArcCatalog or toolbox. I have to open ArcCatalog through a separate window.  Earlier, when I used to open ArcMap, the window used to show both display window as well as all other options of ArcCatalog.

Could anyone suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have closed the Catalog window of ArcMap.

To open it go to the Main Menu and choose Windows | Catalog.